# uploading CVS document into R

Tags: r

I am an R beginner. I am trying to upload a CSV file into R. However, When I upload the dataset, I am getting strange structures and I cannot figure out how to solve this problem. My CSV original document looks like so:

```
1,"male","other",39.1500015258789,"yes","no","yes","yes",6.19999980926514,8.09000015258789,0.200000002980232,0.889150023460388,12,"high","other"
```

When upload into R my data frame looks like so:

```
"\"1"  "\"\"male\"\""   "\"\"other\"\""        39.2 "\"\"yes\"\""
```

I tried to remove the slash and the quotation mark by using the following function: `new <- read_csv("CollegeDistance.csv", TRUE, quote = "")`. However , it does not really help.

Does someone now how to solve this problem. Thanks, by advance.

Comment: Do just `read_csv("data.csv", col_names  = FALSE)`, because there aren't column names in your presented file.

Comment: Hi, 
I tried this: new <- read_csv("CollegeDistance.csv", TRUE, quote = """)   but I am getting error

Comment: Col_names, is also not working

Comment: Please provide more than one line of the csv file

Comment: ,"gender","ethnicity","score","fcollege","mcollege","home","urban","unemp","wage","distance","tuition","education","income","region"
1,"male","other",39.1500015258789,"yes","no","yes","yes",6.19999980926514,8.09000015258789,0.200000002980232,0.889150023460388,12,"high","other"
2,"female","other",48.8699989318848,"no","no","yes","yes",6.19999980926514,8.09000015258789,0.200000002980232,0.889150023460388,12,"low","other"
3,"male","other",48.7400016784668,"no","no","yes","yes",6.19999980926514,8.09000015258789,0.200000002980232,0.889150023460388,12,"low","other"

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the second argument from TRUE to FALSE, because the file is only one row and can therefore not use it as column names.
`new <- read_csv("CollegeDistance.csv", FALSE, quote = "")`

Comment: if I try your code : new <- read_csv("CollegeDistance.csv", FALSE, quote = "")    I am getting the following output:                                                                        
 X1    X2     X3     X4     X5     X6     X7    X8    X9    X10   X11  
   <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1 "\""  "\"\"~ "\"\"~ "\"\"~ "\"\"~ "\"\"~ "\"\~ "\"\~ "\"\~ "\"\~ "\"\~
 2 "\"1" "\"\"~ "\"\"~ "39.1~ "\"\"~ "\"\"~ "\"\~ "\"\~ "6.1~ "8.0~ "0.2~

Comment: If I use the following (original ) function: new1 <- read_csv("CollegeDistance.csv", quote = "") I am getting the following output:A tibble: 4,739 x 15
   `"`    `""gender""`     `""ethnicity""` `""score""` `""fcollege""`
   <chr>  <chr>            <chr>                 <dbl> <chr>         
 1 "\"1"  "\"\"male\"\""   "\"\"other\"\""        39.2 "\"\"yes\"\"" 
 2 "\"2"  "\"\"female\"\"" "\"\"other\"\""        48.9 "\"\"no\"\""